# If I have two orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^3$...

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

If I have two orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{u}$ & $\mathbf{v}$ (so both unit length).  and another vector $\mathbf{w}$ that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$ (not to $\mathbf{v}$ though).

How can I find -with least calculations & roots- a third orthonormal vector to both $\mathbf{u}$ & $\mathbf{v}$ (this vector may be in the direction of w, but doesn't have to be, just that I have an orthonormal basis. $\mathbb{R}^3 = \text{span}\{\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$

EDIT: it seems I have now 3 methods: using Gram-Schmidt ($\mathbf{w}' = \mathbf{w}- \frac{\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{v} - \frac{\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{u}$). Using cross products and finally solving the equations that the dot products between the vectors must be 0. Guess it is up to experience what is easiest? Or is there anymore advice/am I doing something stupid?

Comment: To get $\mathbb{R}$, write \mathbb{R}, and to get $\{$ and $\}$, write \{ and \}, respectively.

As for your math question, is $\mathbf{w} = \frac{1}{\Vert \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}\Vert} \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$ simple enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing an additional vector $w$ orthogonal to $u$ doesn't help, because for example it could just be $w = -v$.  Use the cross product $w = u \times v$ to get your vector $w$, for example see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Well it does help as you can for example use Gram-Schmidt process to find a projection of w on the u,v plane (and then use w - proj(w) for the orthogonal vector). I am asking this because a lot of question I have involve this.